# materialize css checkbox not working with model variable

Tags: angular, checkbox, materialize

this is html

```
<div class="checkbox checkbox-circle">
       <label>
        <input type="checkbox" [attr.checked]="isSelected ? true : null" class="filled-in"
          (change)="rowToggleSelection(row,$event,i)" />
        <span></span>
      </label>
</div>
```

there is a button that set `true/false` to `isSelected` and it works fine till i change the value of checkbox by clicking on checkbox itself. After click on checkbox it stops working from the buton.

Comment: You should be using two way binding for `attr.checked` i.e. `[(attr.checked)]="isSelected"` to make sure that the value is changed if you checked it manually. Also I think you should not use ternary operator to put value to `isSelected` as it is already a boolean.

Comment: are there any reason to not use [(ngModel)]?

Comment: @isAif , i am using this is loop every object has isSelected, when i used ngModel then on click of single value it selected all

Comment: @Eliseo in loop this does not work properly

Comment: @isAif yes i am using the same, `[(attr.checked)]="item.isSelected"` and this shows all items selected by default

Comment: Try `[(checked)]="item.isSelected"` instead of `[(attr.checked)]="item.isSelected"`

Comment: @isAif tried even `[(value)]`

Comment: See this stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-gyd5a9?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @SunilGarg, see how using ngModel in my answer. For me it's more simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing worked for me, so i used the material icons to achieve the same

```
<!-- checked -->
<i class="material-icons label-icon active" *ngIf="isSelected">radio_button_checked</i>
<!-- un-checked -->
<i class="material-icons label-icon" *ngIf="!isSelected">radio_button_unchecked</i>
```

and some css

```
.label-icon {
    font-size: 15px;
    &.active {
        color: $color-active;
    }
}
```

this is working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

using ngModel, see how you needn't anything more in .ts

```
<form *ngFor="let item of items" class="checkbox checkbox-circle">
       <label>
        <input name="ck" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="item.isSelected"  class="filled-in"
           />
          <span>{{item.name}}</span>
      </label>
</form>
<pre>
{{items|json}}
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Materialize [checkbox](https://materializecss.com/checkboxes.html) uses `checked` not `attr.checked` to mark it as checked.

typescript file

```
// items to use as checkbox
public items = [
    {
      name: "first",
      isSelected: false
    },
    {
      name: "second",
      isSelected: true
    }
  ];

// toggle the checkbox
toggleCheckbox(item) {
    item.isSelected=!item.isSelected;
}
```

template file

```
<form *ngFor="let item of items" class="checkbox checkbox-circle">
       <label>
        <input type="checkbox" [checked]="item.isSelected" class="filled-in"
          (change)="toggleCheckbox(item)" />
          <span>{{item.name}}</span>
      </label>
</form>
```